# How can I have the console read the number of things a user inputs?

Tags: c#, string, numbers, user-input

I am creating a very basic version of Yatzy. What I want to happen is that after the user rolls the dice the first time, choose which numbers to keep and roll the dice for again is that only the number of dice that the wants to reroll are rerolled. I don't know how to do that. I think it has to do with the console reading the number of dice the user keeps which I can't figure out how to do.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int firstCount = 1;
        int secCount = 1;
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Yatzy!");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 'Enter' to start the game.");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
        do
        {
            Random randomizer = new Random();
            int randomNumber = randomizer.Next(1, 7);
            Console.Write("{0} ", randomNumber);
            firstCount = firstCount + 1;
        } while (firstCount < 6);
        Console.WriteLine("Which numbers would you like to keep?");
        Console.Write("");
        string keepNumbers = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press 'Enter' to roll again.");
        Console.ReadLine();
        do
        {
            Random randomizer = new Random();
            int randomNumber = randomizer.Next(1, 7);
            Console.Write("{0} ", randomNumber);               
            secCount = secCount + 1;
        } while (secCount < 5);
        Console.Write("{0} ", keepNumbers);
    }
```

Comment: Not your answer, but start moving the creation of the Random variable outside the loops.

Comment: You need to keep the roll result, right now it's recreated each time and not stored anywhere. I see you are very new to programing so I suggest you go very basic and simply create 5 integer variable,1 for each die and go from there.